# Error 3358 : The InitiatedType field is missing

Tags: php, opayo

Have been using SagePay integration v4 for some months now and since midnight tonight suddenly receiving lots of:

"Error 3358 : The InitiatedType field is missing".

What have SagePay changed?  The Direct Integration document I've got is dated 24/05/19, so over a year old so it's possible that this has been updated but not communicated out

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly I just got off the phone from Sagepay and they told me a different story, apparently it's an error in a release they put live today.

Really annoying considering only V4 supports 3DSv2

Comment: Interesting...  I've basically been told to either add some additional fields or revert to version 3.  If I remain on version 4 then there's a risk that they may make further changes in the future which would break.  Like you say, it's very frustrating because version 3 doesn't support 3DSv2

Comment: Hi just wanted to update this.
In the end we were told the same to revert to V3 and that version 4 will update at a moments notice so shouldn't really be used.
Disappointed by the confused messaging received from SagePay on this issue, why even make 4 public as it's not really fit for production use as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard back from SagePay and this is related to changes that were made this morning relating specifically to using stored credit cards due to changes being implemented by the banks.  This has resulted in additional fields being added.

One point that was made is that Version 4 is considered not suitable for use in production as it is susceptible to having changes implemented without any notice.  This is counter to what I was told last year (the gent I spoke to apologised for this).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem at the end of 2020 while I was implementing 3DSv2 changes for SagePay for Direct Integration - Token Payments where you can store your credit card details and next time you can use a token to do a payment.

After a quick chat with Sage Pay support I realized that I wasn't passing the COFUsage and InitiatedType fields to the Sage Pay REST API. Here is how they should be;

When you are saving the card details for the first time, then you should additionally pass these values;

> "&InitiatedType=CIT&COFUsage=FIRST"

After you save your card details and when you want to use the same card details again for your next payment, then values should be as follows;

> &InitiatedType=CIT&COFUsage=SUBSEQUENT

Please see further details below;

**First time payment with a card - Save card details true**

VPSProtocol=4.00&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=VENDORNAME&VendorTxCode=b9797f9e614beb11a812000d3a86a3ce-121349&Amount=21.95&Currency=GBP&Description=CRM Cart:QUO-02178-M0P8F9- RICHARD sdvsdv &CardType=VISA&CardHolder=CHALLENGE&CardNumber=4929 0000 0000 6&BillingSurname=sdvsdv&BillingFirstnames=RICHARD&BillingAddress1=15 Whatley Road Test&BillingCity=Bristol&BillingPostCode=BS82NA&BillingCountry=GB&DeliverySurname=sdvsdv&DeliveryFirstnames=RICHARD&DeliveryAddress1=15 Whatley Road Test&DeliveryCity=Bristol&DeliveryPostCode=BS82NA&DeliveryCountry=GB&ExpiryDate=1223&CV2=123&StoreToken=1&BillingAddress2=Flat 3&DeliveryAddress2=Flat 3&CustomerEMail=testcustomer@gmail.com&ApplyAVSCV2=0&Apply3DSecure=0&ClientIPAddress=192.168.0.1&AccountType=E&VendorData=CRM CartQUO02178M0P8F9 RICHARD sdvsdv &CreateToken=1&ThreeDSNotificationURL=https://YOURWEBSITE.localhost/umbraco/Surface/Ecommerce/ThreeDSecureCallback?cartSelector=0978bb20-c6e1-e811-a89c-002248005489:::ContactId&BrowserJavaEnabled=0&BrowserJavascriptEnabled=0&BrowserColorDepth=0&BrowserAcceptHeader=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9&BrowserLanguage=en-GB&BrowserUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36&ChallengeWindowSize=05&BrowserScreenHeight=0&BrowserScreenWidth=0&BrowserTZ=0

**Error:**

VPSProtocol=4.00&Status=INVALID&StatusDetail=3358 : The InitiatedType field is missing.&VPSTxId={A0AA8834-2ABE-AD2B-AFBA-07F6E1CB5B64}&SecurityKey=SWLLVFRUHB

**Addition for successful transaction:**
postData+="&InitiatedType=CIT&COFUsage=FIRST"

**Second payment - pay with existing**

VPSProtocol=4.00&TxType=PAYMENT&Vendor=VENDORNAME&VendorTxCode=fb1baaa8664beb11a8120022481a236c-124949&Amount=21.95&Currency=GBP&Description=CRM Cart:QUO-02179-F6P4Z6 - RICHARD sdvsdv &CardType=NONE&BillingSurname=RICHARD&BillingFirstnames=sdvsdv&BillingAddress1=15 Whatley Road Test&BillingCity=Bristol&BillingPostCode=BS82NA&BillingCountry=GB&DeliverySurname=sdvsdv&DeliveryFirstnames=RICHARD&DeliveryAddress1=15 Whatley Road Test&DeliveryCity=Bristol&DeliveryPostCode=BS82NA&DeliveryCountry=GB&CV2=123&Token={492DBEEE-F38E-163D-ECF3-4B363A11159A}&StoreToken=1&BillingAddress2=Flat 3&DeliveryAddress2=Flat 3&ApplyAVSCV2=0&Apply3DSecure=0&ClientIPAddress=192.168.0.1&AccountType=E&CreateToken=0&ThreeDSNotificationURL=https://YOURWEBSITE.localhost/umbraco/Surface/Ecommerce/ThreeDSecureCallback?cartSelector=0978bb20-c6e1-e811-a89c-002248005489:::ContactId&BrowserJavaEnabled=0&BrowserJavascriptEnabled=0&BrowserColorDepth=0&BrowserAcceptHeader=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9&BrowserLanguage=en-GB&BrowserUserAgent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36&ChallengeWindowSize=05&BrowserScreenHeight=0&BrowserScreenWidth=0&BrowserTZ=0

**Error:**

VPSProtocol=4.00&Status=INVALID&StatusDetail=3358 : The InitiatedType field is missing.&VPSTxId={E035E6FC-1D3C-6930-9DBA-F64E6E5650A0}&SecurityKey=Y3GG7BAEM3

**Addition for successful transaction:**
postData+="&InitiatedType=CIT&COFUsage=SUBSEQUENT"

**Email from Sage Pay:**
[image]

**Sage Pay documentation references:**

- https://www.opayolabs.co.uk/apis/direct?content=direct-credential-file-table
- https://www.opayolabs.co.uk/apis/direct?content=direct-transaction-registration-post
- https://www.opayo.co.uk/library/document/directintegrationandprotocol4guidelinespdf

Comment: They still appear to be finalising the requirements.  When I posted this originally the code was using the guidelines as they were, but SagePay decided to add new mandatory fields in.  We're just holding off implementing v4 until they actually get something nailed down that isn't going to change.

Comment: In case you need it, here is the latest Opayo documentation that explains "What do customers need to do?". Hope it helps somebody. . https://www.opayo.co.uk/support/16/3d-secure-v2-what-do-customers-need-to-do

Also I went live for one of my clients that uses Direct integration - single payment only- at the beginning of 2021, so far so good. Another client that uses Direct integration - single and token payment, will hopefully go live soon. Tests are good for it so far.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like Opayo have a slightly better handle on it than SagePay did.  That link confirms that live won't be ready until July so will hold my horses until then - it causes far too much disruption when it all goes wrong and suddenly you've thousands of customers unable to place an order.